# javascript regular expression match special string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string like this:

```
惊讶! 学会这些 625 单词就可以走遍天下!  
(Animal) ​动物​:  
Dog ​- 狗,     ​Cat ​- 猫,     ​Fish ​- 鱼,     ​Bird ​- 鸟,     ​Cow ​- 牛,     ​Pig ​- 猪,     ​Mouse ​- 老鼠, 
Horse ​- 马,     ​Wing ​- 翅膀,     ​Animal ​- 动物.  
(Transportation) ​交通​:  
Train ​- 火车,     ​Plane ​- 飞机,     ​Car ​- 汽车,     ​Truck ​- 卡车,     ​Bicycle ​- 自行车​
,
```

I want to match `Dog - 狗`,`Fish - 鱼` ...
my regular expression is: `const reg = /(.*)\s*-\s*(.*),/g`, but the result is not what i expect.so how to write a correct one?

my final answer is `[[Dog,狗],[Cat,猫],...]`,I know I should use regular expression, but it has trouble

Comment: Maybe `/(\S*)\s*\u200B?-\s*([^,]*)/g`?

Comment: please note your source string contains many `U+200B` characters (Unicode's Zero width spaces), those might interfere.

Comment: @GrafiCode I use "pdf-parse" parsing the pdf file to get this string... so I'm very confused

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes,I don't know the u200B, so when console on the editor or chrome-console, always has red dot...

Comment: This regex is a very nice idea additionally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(\S+)[\s\u200B]*-[\s\u200B]*([^,]*)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gjV7QE/2).

*Details*:

- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `[\s\u200B]*` - zero or more whitespaces or ZWJ symbol
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[\s\u200B]*` - zero or more whitespaces or ZWJ symbol
- `([^,]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than a comma.